# save button hidden once visit page

Tags: drupal

I have page has content type I need to save it to database, i added save button using hook_form_alter as following

```
function customization_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'media_operator_node_form'){
    $form['buttons']['submit']['#value'] = t('Save');  
  }  
}
```

the problem is:
the save button once visit page is hidden but when scroll to down the button appear

what is the problem and how can i solve it so once visit the page i see the save button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal content types are saved to the database by default.
The code you have posted does not add a save button, it looks to me that it just sets the text on the button to save (which on a content type is the default value anyway).

It sounds like you may be getting confused between the node page and the node edit page but I'm not sure.
You will have to explain your problem a little more clearly.

Comment: yes you are right, I am in edit node page and no need to add above code to page but i still have the same problem the save button is hidden by default but when scroll down the button appear.  the div has the save button <div class="buttons" style="display: none;"> once scrioo down changed to <div class="buttons" style="display: block;">

Comment: Hmm, button appears when you scroll? Sounds like an old IE CSS bug or something.
What browser are you testing in? Have you tested in a 'good' browser such as Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't quite understand your problem.
If you are not reloading you page and the button suddenly appears, it is either a CSS or javascript problem.

Comment: it is not a problem, there is action set display to block on scroll but i do not know where is it?!